# Creating a macro for selecting and deleting cells with a value greater than 3000

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset for every Lower Super Output Area (LSOA) in the UK and their respective  total populations. Included in this dataset is the total for each Local Authority (LAD) which i need to filter out to be left with a table simply of each LSOA and its population.

As an LSOA cannot be over 3000 in population, selecting all cells with a value greater than 3000 and clearing them would be the solution? I wanted to create a macro for this to avoid repeating the process.

Comment: You need to give more information - What have you tried to do? 
Are you able to give an example of the columns etc.
Depending on the columns etc then I can think of ways of doing this which take less than 10 seconds without resorting to a macro.  -  Is creating a macro really the best way of performing this task!

Comment: I have 3 columns. Area Code, Area Name and Total Population, each with 35,104 rows. I have so far used the filter to select values greater than 3000 from the population column, but it does not select/delete the corresponding Code & Name cells also, which i need to do to reduce the dataset to LSOA's (cells with total pop 3000 or less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment

> I have 3 columns. Area Code, Area Name and Total Population, each with
>   35,104 rows.

I am going to assume that the data is in columns A, B, & C

To do this without code you would just sort column c in decending order (Would group all your large numbers together and is optional) Then filter the population column to only show rows greater than 3000, Then you can just select all visible rows & hit delete.  - Takes less than 20 seconds in total.

To do this using a macro try this:

```
Sub deleterows()

   Dim rng as range

    With ActiveSheet

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("A1:C" & .Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">3000"
                With .AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set Rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
                          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    End Sub
```